Deployment with Minikube on Linux Mint fails SSL, works fine on Windows
I've tried to deploy an R-ShinyVerse image on a local Linux Mint machine, but even curl and apt-get install failed due to SSL errors.
My Dockerfile:
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:4.4.1

ARG WHEN
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm

# Install apps
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo curl rclone cron rsyslog procps systemd \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev \
  libxml2-dev libfontconfig1-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev
  
RUN curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | bash

# Install library for R
RUN R -e "options(repos = \
  list(CRAN = 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/${WHEN}/')); \
  if (!require('pacman')) install.packages('pacman'); \
  pacman::p_load(tidyverse, ggplot2, dplyr, httr2, glue, stats, readr, \
  lubridate, jsonlite, qualtRics, here, rmarkdown, \
  formattable, tidyr, shiny, DT, knitr, kableExtra, data.table, \
  tinytex, flextable, officer, stringr, rlang, mailR, geometry, install = T, update = F); \
  tinytex::install_tinytex();"

And a simple .yaml deployment file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-rwmain
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rwmain-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rwmain-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rwmain
        image: rwmain:latest 
        imagePullPolicy: Never

There are no services, so no LoadBalancer/NodePort/...
Result: Even a simple curl to example.net yields a SSL error:
# curl -vvv https://example.net
*   Trying 192.168.1.1:443...
* Connected to example.net (192.168.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, bad certificate (554):
* SSL certificate problem: EE certificate key too weak
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: EE certificate key too weak
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Everything on my Windows 11 machine works as expected—I even set up a cloudflared tunnel connector, and everything functions the same.
Initially, I thought this to be a firewall situation, so I disabled ufw and restarted everything, to no avail.
So my question is: How can I debug this further, and why would the same setup work fine on Windows but fail on Linux Mint?
System information: Minikube v1.34.0, Linux Mint 22 (Cinnamon), Kubernetes v1.31.0, Docker 27.2.0
Edit: When debugging and running openssl s_client -connect example.net:443 -showcerts on the pod in Linux Mint, it uses a 1024-bit Sagemcom RSA key (which I'm assuming is the reason for error) but the host Linux machine, my Windows machine, and my Windows minikube pod all return a Digicert 2048-bit key.

The issue might be SSL certificate verification errors which may be caused by the certificates used by Minikube being expired or misconfigured. To resolve this, you can delete the existing Minikube cluster and start fres bu using minikube delete, followed by making sure the VM was deleted inside VBox, then re-running minikube start should put you back to a good state. Check for any errors while minikube start is running.

@SaiChandraGadde I've deleted and restarted everything twice, always seems to be the same. I didn't see any errors when minikube started.

@SaiChandraGadde But an interesting error, when running openssl s_client -connect example.net:443 -showcerts on the pod in Linux Mint, it uses a 1024-bit Sagemcom RSA  key (which I'm assuming is the reason for error) but the host Linux machine, my Windows machine, and my Windows minikube pod all return a Digicert 2048- bit key. What could be the reason for this, and how do I fix this?

This might be a bizarre case, but it seems like our Spectrum router is injecting some weird, outdated Sagemcom CA certificates when transferring, hence the TLS error. Using literally anything else, like my school's Wifi network or my phone's hotspot fixed the error.
